# Powershell Sorting CSV File

Tags: powershell

I have the following code:

```
$script:DatabaseFile = "C:\NewFolder\test.csv"

[string[]]$database = Get-Content -Path $script:DatabaseFile
[Collections.Generic.List[String]]$script:Database = $database

$script:Database | Out-File $script:DatabaseFile -Encoding ascii
$databaseAsCsvObject = Import-Csv $script:DatabaseFile
$databaseAsCsvObject | sort "Release Group","Email Address" | Export-Csv $script:DatabaseFile
```

`$script:DatabaseFile` contains the following:

```
Release Group,Email Address,Template ID,Time
CDP.HLO.1,test@test.com,Template1,02:00
EDP.HLO.1,test1@test1.com,Template2,03:00
```

This successfully sorts the csv file based on the first two columns.

How can I write the equivalent code without having to save the file, then import it as csv?
Can I just get `$script:Database` as a "CSV" object, and then sort it, and then write it to file only once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$script:Database = @(
[pscustomobject]@{"Release group"="EDP.HLO.1";"Email Address"="test1@test1.com";"Template ID"="Template2";"time"="03:00"},
[pscustomobject]@{"release group"="CDP.HLO.1";"Email Address"="test@test.com";"Template ID"="Template1";"time"="02:00"})

$sorted = $script:Database | Sort-Object "Release Group", "Email Address"

$script:DatabaseFile = "C:\data\test.csv"
$sorted | Export-csv -NoTypeInformation -Path $script:DatabaseFile
```

Okay so I have completely re-written on my first answer. First create your custom object with required headings. Create as many entries as you need. Sort the object, then export to csv :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the awesome answer, I didn't even know you could do that!
I've edited my question a bit, what if I have a List[string] already given to me, would I have to convert it to an array of custom objects? If so how, and then would it actually be easier to just save the file and then import it as csv like I was doing originally?

Comment: I guess it depends how the List[string] is given to you? Are you pulling from `C:\newFolder\test.csv` like your code suggests? If you are you won't have to create any custom objects, just `import-csv`. Can you give an example of where you are pulling the original data from? i.e what format

Comment: See my edited post.
Although it's not very elegant, I think it's more efficient to just write to the file, then import that file as csv, then sort, then write to file again.
Otherwise I assume I'd need to use a for loop to create the custom objects for each row in the csv file.

Comment: Thats true, you would need a for-loop. But from your code there, your reading from `C:\newfolder\test.csv` to get your values anyway? why dont you just use `import-csv` instead of `get-content`

Comment: Because after I read the file (get-content), I need to add to it, so I use get-content so that I'm able to treat it as a List[String] so I can easily add to it.
Am I able to add to an object returned from import-csv?

Comment: It says the type of object returned from Import-Csv is of type Array (Object[]). 
So unfortunately to add to it I'd need to convert it to a List[String] and then back to an array of Objects, which would defeat the purpose of Import-Csv.
What do you think?

Comment: Yeah sounds like the easiest way will be to write to and from the file. You can also look at `convertto-csv` and `convertfrom-csv` but I had no luck getting them to work how I wanted